# Let $a$ be an element of a group and $|a| = 100$. Find $|a^{98}|$ and $|a^{70}|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a$ be an element of a group and $|a| = 100$. Find $|a^{98}|$ and $|a^{70}|$.

I used a theorem for this. The theorem stated, Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group and let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $\langle a^k\rangle = \langle a^{\gcd(n, k)}\rangle$ and $|a^k| = n/\gcd(n, k)$. However, I'm not sure if my approach is correct
.

Comment: Your approach is correct but I think it will be |a^k| in the theorem.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Please include the problem in the post, not just the subject line.

Comment: You are misquoting the theorem: the second part should describe the order of $a^k$, not the order of $a$.

Comment: Ah, yes. It is |a^k| not |a|. Sorry for the typo, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

With the theorem, my answer is:
$|a^{98}|$ = 100/gcd(100, 98) = 100/2 = 50
$|a^{70}|$ = 100/gcd(100, 70) = 100/10 = 10